# What is the probability of $n\geq12$ people having birthdays spread across every month?

Tags: probability

For the solution it is allowed to assume that the probability for being born in any month is the same.

This question is trampling on my mind with such a lasting force that I had to get out of bed and ask the kind people of MathStackexchange for some help for I have to attend school in 6 hours and haven't slept a wink $\ddot\smile$

I really can't get beyond the initial stages.

Thank you,

Silenttiffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question basically asks if you randomly map $n$ items into a set of $12$ items, what is the probability that the mapping is onto (surjective).

This is similar to [Number of surjections from $\{1,...,m\}$ into $\{1,...,n\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716886/number-of-surjections-from-1-m-into-1-n)