# Strange binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

Let $S_r(n) = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m m^r \binom{n}{m}$, where $r$ is a non-negative integer. Show that $S_r(n) = 0$ for $r<n$.

My argument was along the lines of: $(1-z)^n = \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}(-1)^m z^m$, so we differentiate this, multiply by $z$, repeat this $r$ times and then let $z=1$. As $r<n$ all terms on LHS have a factor of $(1-z)$ so all vanish and we're left with $0$.

I wasn't very satisfied with this argument and was wondering if there is a more algebraic approach which also doesn't let it become a horrible, unclear mess?

Comment: The question linked as duplicate doesn't explain *why* this is the number of surjective functions. I found [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264799) [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866173) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122224) do, but not in the question or accepted answer. Maybe [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116932) is the closest.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$S_r(n) = r!  [z^r] \sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \exp(mz) {n\choose m}
\\ = r! [z^r] (1-\exp(z))^n.$$

Now $1-\exp(z) = - z - z^2/2 - z^3/6 -\cdots$ so $(1-\exp(z))^n =
(-1)^n z^n + \cdots$. Hence we get zero from the coefficient extractor
in $z$ when $r\lt n.$ This question has appeared here with some
regularity.

Comment: Would you remind me, please, what  $[z^r]$ signifies?

Comment: This is a [coefficient extractor for formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).

Comment: Thank you, I haven’t seen that.

Comment: I wrote an answer along the same lines, but didn't post until now because I was worried it was too close. Then I thought that maybe an explanation without $\left[x^r\right]$ might be useful for some people. If you disagree, I will delete my answer.

Comment: It looks useful to me. (+1).

Answer (score 3):

**[Exponential Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF))**

Here is a different presentation along the lines of Marko Riedel's answer.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}\color{#C00}{S_r(n)}
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}\color{#C00}{\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^mm^r\binom{n}{m}}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^me^{mx}\binom{n}{m}\tag{1b}\\[3pt]
&=\left(1-e^x\right)^n\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=x^n\left(\frac{1-e^x}x\right)^n\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Comparing coefficients of $x^r$ between the left hand side of $\text{(1a)}$ and $\text{(1d)}$ shows that $S_r(n)=0$ for $r\lt n$.

---

**Induction**

This can also be proven by induction.

For $r=0$ and $n\gt r$, the Binomial Theorem gives
$$
\begin{align}
S_0(n)
&=\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^m\binom{n}{m}\tag{2a}\\
&=(1-1)^n\tag{2b}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Assume that $S_k(n-1)=0$ for all $k\lt n-1$. Then, for $1\le r\lt n$,
$$
\begin{align}
S_r(n)
&=\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^mm^r\binom{n}{m}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n(-1)^mm^r\frac nm\binom{n-1}{m-1}\tag{3b}\\
&=n\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{m+1}\color{#C00}{(m+1)^{r-1}}\binom{n-1}{m}\tag{3c}\\
&=-n\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}(-1)^m\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}m^k\binom{r-1}{k}}\binom{n-1}{m}\tag{3d}\\
&=-n\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\binom{r-1}{k}S_k(n-1)\tag{3e}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ definition of $S$
$\text{(3b):}$ $r\ge1$ so we can leave out the $m=0$ term
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ $\binom{n}{m}=\frac nm\binom{n-1}{m-1}$
$\text{(3c):}$ substitute $m\mapsto m+1$
$\text{(3d):}$ Binomial Theorem
$\text{(3e):}$ definition of $S$
$\text{(3f):}$ Since $k\le r-1\lt n-1$, we have $S_k(n-1)=0$ by assumption

Thus, by induction, $S_r(n)=0$ for all $r\lt n$.

Answer (score 2):

For a combinatorial proof, interpret the sum as an inclusion-exclusion formula for a certain type of function, and observe that such functions do not exist when $r<n$.