# Is there an equation for how many ways there are to assign k numbers to numbers 1 to n such that each number appears at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, there are k<sup>n</sup> total ways of assigning k numbers to n numbers, but not all of the assignments use all k numbers.
Let f(n,k) be the number of ways of assigning the numbers so that all k numbers are used. Then $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {C(k,i)f(n,i)}$ = k<sup>n</sup>.

There is a recurrence relationship that can be used to compute f(n,k).

f(n,k) = k(f(n-1,k) + f(n-1, k-1)), where f(n,0)=f(0,k)=0 and f(1,1)=1.

Also, for what it's worth, f(n,n) = n!.

With all this going for it, there must at least be a way of approximating f(n,k).

Comment: There is a summation given formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/716927).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the type of equation I was looking for.