# number of surjective functions from X to Y where card(Y)=k < n =card(X)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatory-logic

### Let $X=\{1,...,n\}$ and $Y=\{1,...,k\}$. If $n\gt\ k$ then the number of surjective functions $f:X\to Y$ $\;\;$is  $\;\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}  (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(k-j)^n$

Here I show what I have done. I can't find my mistake:

Let $A=\{f:X\to Y\}$, $B=\{f:X\to Y:f\text{ surjective}\}$, $C=\{f:X\to Y:f\text{ not surjective}\}$. $\;$ We have that $\;$  $|A|=k^n$ $\;$ so $\;$ $|B|= k^n-|C|$

My strategy to calculate $|C|$ is to differentiate between different cases and I have considered that 
\begin{align}
|C|&=|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-1\}|+|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-2\}|+{}\\
&\qquad+\dots+|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=2\}|+|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=1\}|\\[1ex]
&= k(k-1)^n+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)^n}{2!}+\dots+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots(k-(k-1))^n}{(k-1)!}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}  \binom{k}{j}(k-j)^n
\end{align}

For instance, to calculate $|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-2\}|=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)^n}{2!}$ 
 I take out the first element of Y where I have k possibilities. Then I take out the second element of Y and I have k-1 possibilities. As the order doesn't matter I divide by $2!$ . Now I can make $(k-2)^n$ functions with the rest of elements. (excuse my english)

And then $|B|=k^n-|C|=k^n-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}  \binom{k}{j}(k-j)^n$

Comment: sorry. It is edited. k<n

Comment: What is the source of this exercise? Is it some well-known book?

Comment: When you try to compute $|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-1\}|$, isn't this just the same as computing the number of surjective functions from $X$ to a set of $k-1$ elements? Your computation here is wrong; you don't have $(k-2)^n$ surjective functions, but rather $(k-2)^n$ arbitrary functions.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216360)

Comment: @rogerl i talk about arbitraty functions

Comment: @MathOverview i dont know

Comment: @rogerl i think it is not. But It is relationated

Comment: You say $|\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-2\}|=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)^n}{2!}$. This is incorrect, since the left-hand side purports to count the number of surjective functions from $X$ to a set of $k-2$ elements.

Comment: @rogerl I dont understand you. I just mean this |\{f:X\to Y:|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=k-2,Im(f)\subset(Y), Y=\{1,...,k\}}|=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)^n}{2!}

Comment: @rogerl i finally get it. Ok

Comment: I don't think you're counting the cases correctly. Take |Im(F)| = 3. There are multiple ways for the image of f to be three. You've only considered one of them. What about if y$_1$ has 2 elements in its presage, y$_2$ has 2, and y$_3$ has n-4?