# Find the number of functions (union of sets to a set)

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I'm dealing with the following problem. I have two finite sets $A$ and $B$, with $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$. I should determine how many functions

$f : \mathit A \cup \mathit B \to \{0, 1, 2\}$

there are, such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

The answer for a function

$f : X \to Y$, with $|X| = m$ and $|Y| = n$

would be $n^m$. I've tried to use the same idea to solve my problem, but I'm stuck at some point, since

$|A \cup B|$ = $|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ and $|A \cap B|$ = $|A| + |B| - |A \cup B|$, which makes a loop...

Do you have any hints to solve this?

Comment: The condition $f(a)\neq f(b)$ for all $a\in A, b\in B$ implies that $A$ and $B $ are disjoint, if such an $f$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned elsewhere, $f(a)\ne f(b)$ when $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, indicates that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. That is, if $x\in A\cap B$, then $f(x)\ne f(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Inclusion-Exclusion is mentioned in the question, and we use it here, but we will use it to count the number of surjections from one set to another.

**Counting Surjections**

First, we will compute the number of surjections from the set $A$, of size $m$, onto the set $R$, of size $k$.

Let $S(i)$ be the set of functions on $A$ that do not map onto element $i$ of $R$. An intersection of $j$ of the $S(i)$ contains all functions on $A$ that do not contain $j$ particular elements of $R$ in their range. Since there are $\binom{k}{j}$ choices of the of $j$ missing elements, and for each such intersection, there are $(k-j)^m$ functions that don't map to any of the excluded $j$ elements, we have
$$\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
\begin{align}
N(j)
&=\sum_{|\mathcal{I}|=j}\left|\,\bigcap_{i\in\mathcal{I}} S(i)\,\right|\tag{1a}\\
&=\binom{k}{j}(k-j)^m\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Acording to the [Generalized Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516), the number of elements in none of the $S(i)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\ge0}(-1)^j\binom{j}{0}N(j)
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(k-j)^m\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^m\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&=\stirtwo{m}{k}k!\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: apply the Generalized Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to $(1)$
$\text{(2b)}$: substitute $j\mapsto k-j$
$\text{(2c)}$: $\stirtwo{m}{k}$ is a [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

That is, $(2)$ gives the number of surjections from a set of size $m$ onto a set of size $k$.

**Answering the Question**

Given $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, suppose $|f(A)|=j$, $|f(B)|=k$, and $j+k+p=3$. That is, $p$ is the number of elements not in $f(A\cup B)$.

The number of ways to choose the missing values is $\binom{3}{p}$.

For each choice of missing values, the number of ways to assign values to $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ is $\binom{3-p}{k}$.

For each assignment of values, $(2)$ says that the number of functions is $\stirtwo{m}{k}k!\stirtwo{n}{3-p-k}(3-p-k)!$.

Therefore, the number of functions $f:A\cup B\to\{0,1,2\}$ so that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ implies that $f(a)\ne f(b)$, is
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{p=0}^3\sum_{k=0}^{3-p}\binom{3}{p}\binom{3-p}{k}\color{#C00}{\stirtwo{m}{k}k!}\color{#090}{\stirtwo{n}{3-p-k}(3-p-k)!}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^3\sum_{k=0}^{3-p}\binom{3}{p}\binom{3-p}{k}\color{#C00}{\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}i^m}
\color{#090}{\sum_{j=0}^{3-p-k}(-1)^{3-p-k-j}\binom{3-p-k}{j}j^n}\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^3\sum_{k=0}^{3-p}(-1)^{3-p}\binom{3}{p}\binom{3-p}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}i^m
\sum_{j=0}^{3-p-k}(-1)^j\binom{3-p-k}{j}j^n\tag{3c}\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^3\sum_{k=0}^{3-p}(-1)^{3-p}\frac{3!}{p!}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\frac1{i!(k-i)!}i^m
\sum_{j=0}^{3-p-k}(-1)^j\frac1{j!(3-p-k-j)!}j^n\tag{3d}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=0}^{3-i}\sum_{p=0}^{3-i-j}(-1)^{3-p-i-j}\frac{3!\,i^mj^n}{p!(3-p-i-j)!i!j!}2^{3-p-i-j}\tag{3e}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=0}^{3-i}(-1)^{3-i-j}\frac{3!\,i^mj^n}{(3-i-j)!i!j!}\tag{3f}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
3(2^m+2^n-2)&\text{when }m,n\gt0\\
3^{m+n}&\text{when $m=0$ or $n=0$}\\
\end{array}
\right.}\tag{3g}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: preceding argument
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $\text{(2b)}$
$\text{(3c)}$: redistribute powers of $-1$
$\text{(3d)}$: expand the binomial coefficients as ratios of factorials and cancel
$\text{(3e)}$: sum in $k$: $\sum\limits_{k=i}^{3-p-j}\frac1{(k-i)!(3-p-k-j)!}=\frac{2^{3-p-i-j}}{(3-p-i-j)!}$
$\text{(3f)}$: sum in $p$: $\sum\limits_{p=0}^{3-i-j}\frac{(-2)^{3-p-i-j}}{p!(3-p-i-j)!}=\frac{(-1)^{3-i-j}}{(3-i-j)!}$
$\text{(3g)}$: when $m,n\gt0$, the $i=0$ and $j=0$ terms vanish
$\phantom{\text{(3g):m}}$ $(i,j)=(2,1)$ gives $3\cdot2^m$
$\phantom{\text{(3g):m}}$ $(i,j)=(1,2)$ gives $3\cdot2^n$
$\phantom{\text{(3g):m}}$ $(i,j)=(1,1)$ gives $-6$
$\phantom{\text{(3g):}}$ when $m=0$, the sum in $i$ is $0^{3-j}\frac{6j^n}{j!}$; of which, the sum in $j$ is $3^n$
$\phantom{\text{(3g):}}$ when $n=0$, the sum in $j$ is $0^{3-i}\frac{6i^m}{i!}$; of which, the sum in $i$ is $3^m$

**Generalization to Other Ranges**

The argument and formulas above, except $\text{(3g)}$, can be generalized to ranges other than $\{0,1,2\}$ simply by replacing $3$ with the size of the other range.

Comment: After I answered this question, I looked for places where the number of surjections from one set to another are computed. The first reference I see on math.SE is [Counting the number of surjections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216360/counting-the-number-of-surjections). Interestingly, that question also uses a range with $3$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small hint, for that property to be true, apart from the sets having to be disjoint as Bernard said in the comments, observe that f must take A and B to two disjoint subsets of {0,1,2}.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given constraints in the question, we have

- $f(A) \not = \{\}$
- $f(B) \not = \{\}$
- $f(A)\cap f(B) =\{\}$
- $f(A)\cup f(B) \subseteq \{0,1,2\}$

As all the possible cases are relatively small, let me enumerate as follows.

My notation $|f_A|$ represents the number of possible functions that map from $A$ to $f(A)$.

| Case | $f(A)$ | $f(B)$ | $|f_A|$ | $|f_B|$ | $|f_{A\cup B}|$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $\{0\}$ | $\{1,2\}$ | $1$ | $2^n$ | $1\times2^n$ |
| 2 | $\{1\}$ | $\{0,2\}$ | $1$ | $2^n$ | $1\times2^n$ |
| 3 | $\{2\}$ | $\{0,1\}$ | $1$ | $2^n$ | $1\times2^n$ |
| 4 | $\{0,1\}$ | $\{2\}$ | $2^m$ | $1$ | $2^m\times 1$ |
| 5 | $\{0,2\}$ | $\{1\}$ | $2^m$ | $1$ | $2^m\times 1$ |
| 6 | $\{1,2\}$ | $\{0\}$ | $2^m$ | $1$ | $2^m\times 1$ |
| 7 | $\{0\}$ | $\{1\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |
| 8 | $\{0\}$ | $\{2\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |
| 9 | $\{1\}$ | $\{0\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |
| 10 | $\{1\}$ | $\{2\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |
| 11 | $\{2\}$ | $\{0\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |
| 12 | $\{2\}$ | $\{1\}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1\times 1$ |

However,

- Case 7 is already in either  case 1 or case 5.
- Case 8 is already in either  case 1 or case 4.
- Case 9 is already in either  case 2 or case 6.
- Case 10 is already in either  case 2 or case 4.
- Case 11 is already in either  case 3 or case 6.
- Case 12 is already in either  case 3 or case 5.

Thus the total is
\begin{align}
T
&= 3(1\times 2^n) + 3(2^m\times1) - 6\\
&= 3(2^n+2^m-2)
\end{align}